# Python Packing int32 but doesn't work?

Tags: python, c++, binary, packing

I have been at this all day and I can't seem to find a solution :(

I have a header for a file I want to create (I'm parsing an obj file in Python to output into binary data to be loaded up in my C++ game engine).

Here is the C++ definition of the Mesh Header

```
struct MeshHeader
{
    unsigned short _vertex_size;
    uint32 _vertex_count;
    unsigned short _index_buffer_count;
    short _position_offset;
    unsigned short _position_component_count;
    short _uv_offset;
    unsigned short _uv_component_count;
    short _normal_offset;
    unsigned short _normal_component_count;
    short _tangent_offset;
    unsigned short _tangent_component_count;
    short _binormal_offset;
    unsigned short _binormal_component_count;
    short _colour_offset;
    unsigned short _colour_component_count;
};
```

Where uint32 is basically a typedef from uint32_t from stdint.h....
So judging from this, the first three member vars are 2 bytes, 4 bytes, 2 bytes respectively, yes?

This is how I read it into the structure

```
fread(&_header, sizeof(MeshHeader), 1, f);
```

_vertex_size gets sets correctly to 56, but _vertex_count gets set to 65536. If I change its data type to uint16 (unsigned short) it gets set correctly to 36. But why? 
I am using the `pack("<I")` function(knowing my machine is little endian).

This is my packing code in python

```
    f.write(pack('<H', self._vertex_size))
    f.write(pack('<I', self._vertex_count))
    f.write(pack('<H', self._index_buffer_count))
    f.write(pack('<h', self._position_offset))
    f.write(pack('<H', self._position_component_count))
    f.write(pack('<h', self._uv_offset))
    f.write(pack('<H', self._uv_component_count))
    f.write(pack('<h', self._normal_offset))
    f.write(pack('<H', self._normal_component_count))
    f.write(pack('<h', self._tangent_offset))
    f.write(pack('<H', self._tangent_component_count))
    f.write(pack('<h', self._binormal_offset))
    f.write(pack('<H', self._binormal_component_count))
    f.write(pack('<h', self._colour_offset))
    f.write(pack('<H', self._colour_component_count))
```

Following the specs of the struct.pack function ( https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html )... H is unsigned short (2 bytes) I is unsigned integer (4 bytes) and h is a short (2 bytes) which match exactly what I have specified in my C MeshHeader class, is it not?

I've been pulling out my hair the past few hours (and I don't have much of it left!). Any suggestions on what could be happening?

Here is a snapshot of the header file in Sublime Text 3 btw 
http://gyazo.com/e15942753819e695617390129e6aa879

Comment: Depending on how your C++ code was compiled, there may be extra bytes being added between structure members to align them on 32- or 64-bit boundaries which the computer would be able to read and write more efficiently than ones which are non-aligned. There may be a compiler option to disable this, something like `-StructPack`...

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! I have tried this with both 32 bit and 64 bit builds using visual studio 2013 community edition. Both yield the same results i am getting above.

Comment: Changing the architecture, especially to something with a larger word size, may not fix this. You need to explicitly modify how the structure is packed.

Comment: How could I do this? 
And are you on about doing this python side or C side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @martineau mentioned, what you're seeing is [C struct packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/). The compiler adds padding between non-word size members to optimize memory access. You can disable this with certain `#pragma` directives. For Visual C, the syntax is `#pragma pack(1)` as explained in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx). In the following example I also use `push` and `pop` to restore the packing to its previous value. Proper packing is important for efficient memory access, so changing it should only be reserved to structures you write to disk.

```
// align on 1-byte
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct MeshHeader
{
    unsigned short _vertex_size;
    uint32 _vertex_count;
    unsigned short _index_buffer_count;
    short _position_offset;
    // ...
};
// restore alignment
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Note that even with struct packing avoided, you may still have issues with [endianity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Writing structures to disk assumes you have full control and knowledge ahead of time of both writer and reader. You can make your life easier by using a proper serialization library. There are many, but a few examples that support both C and Python are [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) and [Avro](https://avro.apache.org/).

Comment: I just come across this following the last reply! Thanks though :) 

And I only forced the little endian to make sure it wasnt an endian issue my end. I shall remove that now.

Thanks all :)

Comment: Another quick question - If I were to make all these integers, will my problem go away? 
(i.e. I wouldnt need to worry about the pack push/pop and padding issues?)

Or would this cause issues porting from 32/64 machines?

Comment: It will go away for 32-bit but probably stay for 64-bit where the alignment is 8 bytes. You should really consider `protobuf` or something similar. I think [Cap'n Proto](https://capnproto.org/) lets you even use the serialized objects as a normal struct so the transition should be easy.

Comment: Great, thanks so much guys! 
I'll get looking at them tomorrow, spent all day writing my 10th obj loader. It's the last one, I swear!

Comment: IMHO, software developers have more important issues to worry about than the one structure padding was designed to avoid. In the shop I managed, we decided to default to always using one-byte packing (which means never add padding) and that we would worry about optimizing memory access later should it ever be necessary — and it never was.